# How to get the content of <script> via simple_html_dom

Tags: simple-html-dom

I'm parsing text using [SIMPLE HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).
I read the documentation but didn't find how to get the content of . 
I want to get the this line `/uploads/music/3/38/29_macho_skr-ft-a.l.a.m-repa-goydm.mp3` from this script. Is it possible? Any helps appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">           
var flashvars = {};     
flashvars.skin = '/templates/topmusic/i/nobius_mk2/skin.xml';   
flashvars.playlistxml = '<track><location>/uploads/music/3/38/29_macho_skr-ft-a.l.a.m-repa-goydm.mp3</location><creator>Macho_SkR ft A.L.A.M 2014-New</creator><title>Repa Goydm Manhattan Prod.</title></track>';  
flashvars.autoplay = 'false';   
flashvars.volume    = '80';     
flashvars.shuffle = 'false';    
flashvars.repeat = 'true';  
flashvars.key = '9GXNDFPR9ZPG1EPA1JHV';     
flashvars.mousewheelfix = 'true';       
var params = {};            
var attributes = {};    
attributes.id = 'ep_player1';           
swfobject.embedSWF( '/engine/player/ep_player.swf');     
</script>
```

Comment: What have your tried?

Comment: 1. `foreach($html->find('.news_cont_pad script') as $element){
 echo $element->outertext;
}`

2.`preg_match('#<location[^>]+>(.+?)</location>#ims', $link_down, $str);`
Nothing didn't get it...

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this? @Wojciech Żółtak

Comment: @WebDevB, Yes! Look to answer.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the answer:

```
foreach($html->find('.news_cont_pad script[defer="defer"]') as $element)
    {
            $linkkk = $element->innertext; 
            $link_e = explode('location', $linkkk);
            $aaaa=$link_e[1];
            $rest_r = substr($aaaa, 0, -2);  
            $rest_link = substr($rest_r, 1); 
            $rest_linkaa[] = 'http://xxx.xx'.$rest_link;
    }
```